# CSS Layout breaks on zoom in

Tags: css, html

I am designing a small web page and it is going fine. However yesterday I encountered a problem and I spent more than 6 hours trying different things (min-width,floats etc) nut nothing is solving the issue. I am using %ages to specify widths .

All I want is that my web page should display same when I zoom in on browser. But right now when I zoom in on chrome the logo remains at its place but other navigation elements in the list jump around and clutter together. I don't want this to happen. Similarly in footer the copy right text doesn't stay in line when zooming in on chrome (ctrl+ +). What should I do . Please help.
Here is the url .
http://contestlancer.com/salon/

Thanks
Ahmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use twitter bootstrap. Its a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It not only makes your page responsive, you will also get many in built templates to make your website to have a rich look.

You can download the full library from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: Outstanding. I knew about Bootstrap but never used it just downloaded some examples and bang it was just I needed. Thanks a million

Comment: "You want so find a solution to your problem? Forget about it. Just use this thing."

Answer (score 0):

Change this property if you decide to keep your current site

```
.navigation{
  min-width:900px;
}
```

It's using a percentage now, so whenever you resize the page, it tries to fit all of the elements within the resized view. By making it a static width, you shouldn't have this problem.

Tested in Chrome and worked as you desired.